# How could I start a loading spinner after submitting a form and during running the script and stop loading after script finishes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with a submit input

```
<input type="submit" class="download">
```

which is responsible of running a php & java scripts that download some files , I want to start a loading spinner on the button when it's clicked and continue while the script is running .

Here is the loading function , It works with specific timeout , I want it or a similar one to work during running the script and until it finishes running.

```
$('.download').on('click', function() {
var $this = $(this);
setTimeout(function(){$this.button('loading'); $this.button('reset');,8000););
```

Comment: How do you determine when the script has completed the task? Can you include the full code at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use a gif format image of any spinner and set it to `display:none` by default.  Then change the `display` to `block` on button click. Then set it back to `display:none` after the script is done loading.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ladda.js](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/) for nice button spinner examples

```
$('.download').on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.button('loading');
    // Run your script here
    $this.button('reset');

);
```

or if your script has an asynch callback do this instead:

```
$('.download').on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.button('loading');

    runMyScript(function() {
        $this.button('reset');
    });
);
```

Comment: It's both javascript and php scripts

Comment: Do you submit the form then the submit button in clciked or do you call a JS to do something?